# BeautifulSoup: How to scrape exactly one div, while there are many other divs with the same classname in the same hierarchy?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How to scrape exactly one div, while there are many other divs with the same classname in the same hierarchy?

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmld_doc = """
<div class="main">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="css-1wi2w6s enb64yk4">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="css-1wi2w6s enb64yk4">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="css-1wi2w6s enb64yk4">3</div> //div i want
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="css-1wi2w6s enb64yk4">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
"""

doc = BeautifulSoup(htmld_doc, 'html.parser')
rooms = doc.select('div', {"class":"div:nth-of-type(3) > .css-1wi2w6s.enb64yk4'"}, string=True)
for i in rooms:
  print(i.string)
```

Output:

```
None
None
1
None
2
None
3
None
4
```

Expected output:

```
3
```

Comment: How do you know which div you're looking for? Is it always the third? If so, would something like `result = soup.find_all({"class": "css-1wi2w6s enb64yk4"})[2].string` work?

Answer (score 1):

This solution assumes that the div you are targeting is 3rd in the DOM.

```
# find all divs with class of 'enb64yk4'
divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='enb64yk4')

# get text of third div
third_div_text = divs[2].text 

# output: 3
print(third_div_text)
```